# Building fortran library with waf, installing .mod file

Tags: module, fortran, waf

I use waf (http://code.google.com/p/waf/) to build a fortran library (which also uses some c-code).

The corresponding wscript looks like this:

```
 def build(bld):

    bld(
            features = 'fc',
            source   = 'fortran_interface.f90',
            target   = 'fortran_interface.o')
            #install_path = '${PREFIX}/mod')
    #bld.install_files('${PREFIX}/mod','fortran_interface.mod')

    bld(
            features = 'c',
            includes = '../../include',
            source   = 'init_wrapper.c',
            target   = 'init_wrapper.o')

    bld(
            features = 'fc fcstlib',
            use      = 'init_wrapper.o fortran_interface.o',
            target   = 'fortran_interface',
            install_path = '${PREFIX}/lib')
```

The call waf produces looks like this:

```
fc: src/fortran/fortran_interface.f90 -> 
    build/src/fortran/fortran_interface.f90.1.o 
    build/fortran_interface.mod
```

I want to be able to install the `.mod` file to `${PREFIX}/mod`.
I tried `install_path` which has no effect in this case, or install_files which does not work because a) it doesn't look inside the build/ directory and b) because it complains **before** the building if a file is not present.3

Comment: I also use waf to build Fortran projects, however never tried to install module files anywhere, thus do not really have an idea what to do. I think the best thing to do, i think, is to ask your question on http://groups.google.com/group/waf-users Thomas Nagy is very responsive.

Comment: I've posted my question to said group. I will update this post aswell if I get any answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As to this thread (http://groups.google.com/group/waf-users/browse_thread/thread/c771a2f4fedd4e3?pli=1) the answer was to create

- a separate build group

  `bld.add_group()`
- and to use

  `bld.srcnode.find_or_declare(<filename>.mod)`

to make waf look in the build directory for the .mod file.